# Build only part of a git submodule repository with CMake

Tags: c++, git, cmake, build

I have a C++ project with submodule `another_repo`:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── ext
│   └── another_repo
│       └── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
└── src
```

I would like to build *only part* of `another_repo`. That said, I need a new, customized `CMakeLists.txt` to build `another_repo`, instead of using its original one `./ext/another_repo/CMakeLists.txt`.

But how can I do this in the root directory `./CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: You can add another target which builds that *only part* of `another_repo`.

Comment: @Waqar Thanks for your hint. My blunt does not get your point. Could you expand your comment into an answer if you don't mind?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build only a part of `another_repo` then just create a new target which only build the part you want.

For e.g, `another_repo` has following files:

```
another_repo/
│── a.cpp
│── b.cpp
│── c.cpp
```

And you want to build only `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` (assuming they don't depend on `c.cpp`).

In you root directory `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...

set(ANOTHER ext/another_repo)
add_library(part_of_another_repo ${ANOTHER}/a.cpp ${ANOTHER}/b.cpp)
#or add_executable() if it is an executable
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right, so it seems the correct way.